# Trying to sort an API set by date range

Tags: javascript, endpoint, socrata

I've fetched [this set of data](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Health/Rodent-Inspection/p937-wjvj) from New York City's open data API portal and am trying to sort all entries by endpoint `inspection_date` within the past two years. I'd also like to sort the results by the latest times first. However, I'm having trouble getting my endpoints to cooperate. I've read the [API documentation](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/floating_timestamp.html#2.1,) several times over and can't figure out how it works as I'm still rather new to APIs. Would appreciate any pointers anyone can provide.

```html
url.search = new URLSearchParams({
    "$$app_token": app.token,
    "$limit": 5,
    "house_number": house,
    "street_name": street,
    "borough": borough,
    "inspection_date": ????
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [part of the docs](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/) we can see query parameters that we can use.

As you are trying to sort all entries by inspection_date within the past two years, you can use `$order` and `$where` query parameter.

- `$order` : `inspection_date`
- `$where` : `inspection_date between x and y`

change x as the start date and y as the end date. In your case, the x is 2 years from y.

Example with x as '2020-10-08' and y as '2022-10-08':
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/p937-wjvj.json?$order=inspection_date&$where=inspection_date%20between%20%272020-10-08%27%20and%20%272022-10-08%27

to build the query you will add query parameter `$where` and `$order`:

```js
url.search = new URLSearchParams({
    "$$app_token": app.token,
    "$limit": 5,
    "$where":`inspection_date between ${startDate} and ${endDate}`
    "$order":"inspection_date",
    "house_number": house,
    "street_name": street,
    "borough": borough,
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for you patience and guidance. Got it working great!